# I need change this meta refresh redirect structure to window.location method

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect

I have a web-app in NodeJS that make certain redirects in sometimes using the method meta refresh. The problem is that this method are incompatible with Firefox (in Firefox not work meta refresh). And I need that the redirect goes well in all browsers and versions. I understand that the best way is use window.location method, is right?

The structure of the code that make the actual redirect is:

```
module.exports = (outcome) => {
  return "(function(document) {"+
    "var meta = document.createElement('meta');"+
    "meta.setAttribute('http-equiv', 'refresh');"+
    "meta.setAttribute('content', '0;URL=" + outcome + "');"+
    "document.head.appendChild(meta);"+
  "})(document);";
}
```

How would the final code with the window.location method?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href`.

A simple example would be:

```
window.location.href = 'http://example.com';
```

Or wrapped in your function:

```
module.exports = (outcome) => {
  return "(function(document) {"+
    "window.location.href='" + outcome + "';"+
  "})(document);";
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Filype! This work's fine, the problem is that not works in Safari (Desktop/Mobile) under iFrame. Do you know how I can resolve this?